# What's the meaning of IFCOOM, IFC, SAFE_RELEASE macros?

Tags: c++, com, directx

I've been googling for quite a while and haven't found any definitions of these macros. I encountered them looking through [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc656716(v=vs.110).aspx)

I guess it has some relation to COM, DirectX and/or debugging.

Comment: Never come across them, and have programmed extensively in COM in the past so I doubt it's that. Can you not right-click on the macro and go to its definition?

Comment: I'm actually retarded, definition was right here

Answer (score 1):

```
#define IFC(x) { hr = (x); if (FAILED(hr)) goto Cleanup; }
#define IFCOOM(x) { if ((x) == NULL) { hr = E_OUTOFMEMORY; IFC(hr); } }
#define SAFE_RELEASE(x) { if (x) { x->Release(); x = NULL; } }
```

Comment: Pretty much the nastiest macros I've ever seen (especially IFC), but possibly useful to have on this site, so plus one.